# Which tractate talks about the horses of Persia?

Tags: talmud-gemara

I'm looking for a section in the Talmud which I have read before but can't remember where I read it. The section describes how a Rabbi requests that he be buried deep in the land of Israel because when the Persians come and take over the Persians will use the coffins as feeding troughs for their horses. Does anyone recall which tractate and daf this is in?

Answer (score 4):

[Sanhedrin 98](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sanhedrin.98a.21?lang=bi)

> בשעת פטירתו אמר להן העמיקו לי ארוני שאין כל דקל ודקל שבבבל שאין סוס של פרסיים נקשר בו ואין לך כל ארון וארון שבארץ ישראל שאין סוס מדי אוכל בו תבן
>
> At the time of his death, Rabbi Yosei ben Kisma said to his students: Place my coffin deep in the ground, as there is no palm tree that is in Babylonia to which a horse of the Persians will not be tethered when the Persians and Medes go to conquer other lands. And there is no coffin buried in Eretz Yisrael from which a Median horse will not eat straw.